# How to get my code to show programmatically in my html file

Tags: javascript, html, object

i'm trying to get my code to show the objects on webpage as well as the image associated with it and  Each car object should also include a showMore() method. This
method should display a dialogue that displays all the details about
the specific car object.

here's the code:

```
const show = document.getElementById('show');
function carDescription(make, model, colour, image, registrationnumber, price ) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.image = image;
    this.registrationnumber = registrationnumber;
    this.price = price;
};
let car = { make:"Porsche", model:"GT3", colour:"Black", image:"src=https://pictures.topspeed.com/IMG/crop_webp/201210/1200hp-porsche-911-g_1920x1080.webp" , registrationnumber:"LMO 909 GP", price: 1000000};
let car2 = newcarDescription("Ford", "Fiesta", "Red","https://i.ytimg.com/vi/abVgt23rmrA/hqdefault.jpg", "MNO 010 EC",  100000);
let car3 = newcarDescription("Opel", "Corsa", "White","https://img.gumtree.co.za/api/v1/za-pt10-ads/images/a1/a15f67b3-c11c-40b6-85ad-2987e84e956b?rule=s-I3.auto", "KLJ 899 GP",  55000);
let car4 = newcarDescription("Mazda", "CX-5", "Black","https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/d2/0b/54d20b0bee90aaef22a68b5628441832.jpg" ,"TYH 890 GP",  210000);
let car5 = newcarDescription("Toyota", "Hilux", "Gold","https://imganuncios.mitula.net/medium/toyota_hilux_toyota_hilux_1050104654262066309.jpg" ,"HSG 573 EC",  250000);


function print()
{
    let myString = JSON.stringify(car);
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = `<h3>${car}</h3>`
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html onload="print()"  lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cars</title>
</head>

<body >
    <div id="show">

    </div>

    
    <script src="cars.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The print function should make a tag for every element of the car object.

```
let car = { make:"Porsche", model:"GT3", colour:"Black", image:"src=https://pictures.topspeed.com/IMG/crop_webp/201210/1200hp-porsche-911-g_1920x1080.webp" , registrationnumber:"LMO 909 GP", price: 1000000};

(function print()
{
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.innerHTML= car.model;
    document.getElementById("show").appendChild(h3);
})();
```